# Netlogo : Vaccinating different breeds

Tags: simulation, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

My model is representing the spread of influenza through two separate breeds adults and children.

What I would like to do is add separate vaccinations for adults and children, allowing me to specify two vaccination values from the interface giving the chance of the two respective breeds turtles being vaccinated

My current code is below, what I want to be able to do is use the interface value adult-vaccination to vaccinate a percentage of the turtles in that breed.

```
ask turtles with [ adult? = true ]
   [
   if (adult-vaccination = 1) 
   [
    reset-node
    set exposed? false
    set susceptible? false
    set temp-infected? false
    show-turtle
    set color pink
    ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `adult-vaccination` is a probability from 0 to 1, you can probabilistically vaccinate adults like so:

```
ask turtles with [ adult? ] [
  if random-float 1 < adult-vaccination [
    ... ; vaccination code here
  ]
]
```

If you want `adult-vaccination` to actually determine the fraction of the population that is vaccinated, you can do that like so:

```
let adults turtles with [ adult? ]
ask n-of round (adult-vaccination * count adults) adults [
  ...; vaccination code here
]
```

A few other tidbits:

- `variable = true` will be the same as `variable` if `variable` is always `true` or `false`.
- This looks like a perfect opportunity for using [breeds](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#breeds). You would have an `adults` breed and `children` breed. Then you can do things like `ask adults [ do stuff ]` and give adults and children different variables, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I've split my breeds vaccination rates up between children and adults, however Netlogo is giving me a "Expected a constant" error when I try the code below. Can you give another pointer?

ask n-of (child-vaccination-percentage * count turtles with [ adult? ])[
      
    set turtle_status 5 
    set vaccinated? true
    
    show-turtle
    set color white
    ]
  ]

Comment: No problem!

I made a mistake in the code in my answer. I've now corrected it. Sorry about that!

If you have an `adults` breed now, you don't need the `let` line in the new code.

Comment: I've modified my code but I'm now getting this error. This occurs when I have an initial set of 10 adult agents and try to infect 10% of them. "Requested 100 random agents from a set of only 10 agents.
error while observer running N-OF"

Comment: I figured it out I needed to change my vaccination percentages to .10 e.t.c